# How to monitor notification click in Gnome/Linux?

Tags: java, notifications, gnome

I'm using the notifcation (notify-send, notification-daemon) to send alerts to the user.  I was wondering how I would be able to grab if if/when the user clicks on the notification popup, either on the popup, or the menu on the taskbar/panel.  I'm using Java, so if possible, that'd be nice, of if you have any other idea to get a similar looking notification (I understand Java AWT could be used, but I feel it looks a lot worst than the normal notify).

Any help is appreciated, links or anything, doesn't have to be code.  I feel I just don't know what to Google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with java, but the notification system is used to not interrupt a user and I am not aware of features you requested (I talk about notification-daemon and freedesktop notifications specification). However it is possible to add a button (called an action) to the notification bubble, so user can click it and it activate a callback which you set (so you can interact). Maybe it is a solution? If not probably you have to use/write not "system" notification but application specific notifications (like a OSD library or something similar).

- [Actions example in notifications (python)](http://blog.abhijeetr.com/2011/09/adding-buttons-while-using-python.html)
- [Freedesktop specification for actions](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/)